# How to sum all range output in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my simple Question But i want to sum my all range output my code is as flow

```
for b in range (1, 11):
    ui  = (b**b)
    print (ui)
```

The Output is

```
1
------------------
4
------------------
27
------------------
256
------------------
3125
------------------
46656
------------------
823543
------------------
16777216
------------------
387420489
------------------
10000000000
------------------
```

but i want Sum of these answer. please help me.

Comment: Did you get it to work in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator expression within the `sum` function

```
>>> sum(i**i for i in range(1,11))
10405071317
```

Comment: Yes it is, I just showed you it works. If it doesn't work for you, please edit your post to include the code you tried and what error you get.

Comment: Thanks, Cyber ----------------------------------------------------------------------Yes Its Work But If  i want to add all output by my method its possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using your method:

```
sum_ui = 0
for b in range(1,11):
    ui = (b**b)
    sum_ui += ui
    print ui
print sum_ui
```